# Need to pass argument while accessing python json key

Tags: python, json, bash, parameters, arguments

I need to access json file using command line argument

my code is python.py:

```
#########################################
import json
import sys
from sys import argv
from pprint import pprint

with open('cdh/cdh5.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data['projects']['abcd']['track-branch'])

#################################################
```

so , instead of project abcd , i need to pass abcd from command line while executing this python script.

eg1: `python.py abcd`

will do : `pprint(data['projects']['abcd']['track-branch'])`

eg2: `python.py efgh`

will do : `pprint(data['projects']['efgh']['track-branch'])`

i tried doing this:-

`pprint(data['projects']['sys.args']['track-branch'])` but it gives me below error :

```
pprint(data['projects']['sys.argv']['track-branch'])
KeyError: 'sys.argv'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the arguments that you pass in from command line, you need to use `sys.argv` , you have got that correct.

But you should use it as it is, not pass that as a string , like what you are doing.

Also, `sys.argv` is a list of all the arguments from command line, the first element of `sys.argv` is the file that was executed (like `python.py` ). So you need to use  second element. Example  -

```
pprint(data['projects'][sys.argv[1]]['track-branch'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track but sys.argv is an array with the main module at the 0th index and each successive command line argument at index 1, 2, etc. You should change your code to:

```
pprint(data['projects'][sys.argv[1]]['track-branch'])
```